# Python np.where not returning correct indices

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, python-3.9

I am trying to find indices in a 2D array for rows which contain data which is less than or equal to zero so I write this code:

```
print(np.where(data_import == 0))

#the indices which np.where returns
print(data_import[2])  
print(data_import[95])
```

Python then gives me this as an output:

```
(array([95], dtype=int64), array([2], dtype=int64))
[2.50000000e-02 9.49323045e+01 9.42508218e+00]
[  0.64166667 118.8714848    0.        ]
```

While it makes sense that np.where finds data_import[95] I don't understand why it is also giving me data_import[2] which clearly doesn't contain data which is less than or equal to zero.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `data_import[95, 2]` is 0.  The 2nd array is a column index.

Comment: If you want just the row indices, you can do `np.where(data_import == 0)[0]`.

Comment: Thank you. what I really wanted was just the rows because when I was then trying to use np.delete to remove those rows it was interpreting the columns as additional rows to be deleted.